# Onclick event not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below code in html file and i am trying to establish a connection with MS Access backend DB to validate the incoming user.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<script type=”text/javascript” language=”JavaScript” >

// Function to Check the login from MS Access database

function checkLogin() 
{ 
var usname = document.getElementById(‘tbuname’).value;
var pwd = document.getElementById(‘tbpwd’).value;

// Code to connect the MS Access database using java Script

// ” C:\Users\navyatejav\Documents\BSC Payroll Tracking.accdb ” is the MS Access database

var cn = new ActiveXObject(“ADODB.Connection”);

var strConn = “Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Z:\OPERATIONS\BSC Payroll\Advisors\BostonSci_Agent\New\DBR\BSC Payroll Tracking_be.accdb“; 
var rs = new ActiveXObject(“ADODB.Recordset”);


var SQL = “select password from Agents where username = ‘” + usname + “‘”; 
cn.Open(strConn); 
rs.Open(SQL, cn);

if(!rs.eof)
{

if(rs.fields(0).value == pwd) 
location.href=’main.htm?uname=’+usname;
else
alert(‘wrong username or password!’);

}
else
alert(‘wrong username or password!’);

rs.Close(); 
cn.Close();
}

</script>

</head>
<body style=”margin:0;”>
<table width=”1000px” cellpadding=”0? cellspacing=”0?>
<tr>
<td style=”height:200px;background-image:url(images/top.jpg);”>
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Username : <input type=”text” id=”tbuname” name=”tbuname” />
<br />
Password : <input type=”text” id=”tbpwd” name=”tbuname” />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<Button onclick=”checkLogin()”>Login</Button>


</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when i click on login button, nothing happens. Please help!!!

Comment: Nothing jumps right out after a quick scan of your code.  I suggest you put a console.log statement at the beginning of the function to see if it fires.

Comment: Tried. But no luck. Onclick should check the specified table and alert if the user has correct credentials or not. but nothing happening

Comment: Don't edit scripts in a word processor. All your quotes are wrong, they're curly quotes instead of normal ASCII quotes.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I have changed them in notepad yet, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stands resolved. I have added \ in the db path instead of \ which does the trick. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: Dou you mean like: `Z:\\OPERATIONS\\BSC Payroll\\Advisors\\BostonSci_Agent\New\\` ?

Answer (score 0):

90% of this code is not a standar javascript, this code is to be ran only in old version of Microsoft Internet Explorer

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please help me with the replacement fields or guide me specific so that i can do the needful?

Comment: Try just with Internet Explorer only with that browser and open the javascript console with F12 to see errors given and try to relocate  `Z:\OPERATIONS\BSC Payroll\Advisors\BostonSci_Agent\New\DBR\BSC Payroll Tracking_be.accdb"` file to another location simpler than currrent, something like `"C:\temp\users_test.accdb"` @Teja

Comment: The debugger shows  cn.Open(strConn); as invalid file name

Answer (score 0):

Ran your JS through JSHint and it pinged on a bunch. Widdled it down, replacing the unicode (`’` & `”`):

```
// Function to Check the login from MS Access database

function checkLogin() { 
  var usname, pwd, cn, strConn, rs, SQL;
  usname = document.getElementById("tbuname").value;
  pwd = document.getElementById("tbpwd").value;

  cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Z:\OPERATIONS\BSC Payroll\Advisors\BostonSci_Agent\New\DBR\BSC Payroll Tracking_be.accdb"; 
  rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

  SQL = "SELECT password FROM Agents WHERE username = '" + usname + "'"; 
  cn.Open(strConn); 
  rs.Open(SQL, cn);
  if(!rs.eof){
    if(rs.fields(0).value === pwd){
      location.href = "main.htm?uname=" + usname;
    } else {
      alert("wrong username or password!");
    }
  } else {
    alert("wrong username or password!");
  }
  rs.Close(); 
  cn.Close();
}
```

Report on JSHint:

> There is only one function in this file.
>
> It takes no arguments.
>
> This function contains 16 statements.
>
> Cyclomatic complexity number for this function is 3.
>   8 ActiveXObject
>   10    ActiveXObject

Comment: Thank you Twisty. I have replaced my code with your suggested code and yet, nothing working :(

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Console? Alerts? Are you able to connect via ODBC?

Comment: The debugger shows  cn.Open(strConn); as invalid file name

Comment: Check the permission for `Z:\OPERATIONS\BSC Payroll\Advisors\BostonSci_Agent\New\` folder. Make sure that IUSER has Write and Read, or whatever user is running your IIS/App Pool. I would also try changing the DB Name on the FS to something shorter and without spaces. Also if Z: is a mapped drive, make sure the mapping is active and working. Test by creating a DS to in ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in ActiveXObject. 
Only IE has support for ActiveX, so this won't work in any other browser .

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. And Yes. IE is also not working in this case :(